# Probability of Finding One of a Very Few Defective Products in a Large Population

Tags: probability

A manufacturer knows there are $30$ defective widgets in a container of $45700$ widgets.  If he pulls $700$ without replacement, what is the probability he will get at least $1$ defective widget? At least $2$ defective widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of question, it's almost always easier to find the difference to $1$.
If $p$ is the answer to "What is the probability he won't find any defective widgets", the first answer is $1-p$. So, let's find $p$.

The probability of finding no defective widgets with $1$ widget taken is $\frac{45670}{45700}$ since there is only $30$ defective widgets. With $2$ widgets, the probability becomes $\frac{45670}{45700}*\frac{45669}{45699}$ because when we take the second widget, one "good" widget has already be taken.

Iteratively, with 700 widgets, we get $p=\frac{45670*45699*...*44971}{45700*45699*...*45001}$ which simplifies in $p=\frac{45000*44999*...*44971}{45700*45699*...*45671}$ which is approximately $0.6293$.

The answer to the first question is $1-p$ so $0.3707 = 37.07\%$

There was an other way to get this answer, and I'm going to use it for the second answer.

So if we have $p_1$ the probability of having exactly $1$ bad widget, the answer to the second question will be $1-p-p_1$. Let's calculate $p_1$.

There are $\binom{45700}{700}$ ways to take $700$ widgets from $45700$. There are $\binom{45670}{699}$ ways to take $699$ widgets from the good $45670$. Finally, there are $\binom{30}{1}$ ways of taking $1$ bad widget from the bad $30$ ones.

As a consequence, we have $p_1 = \frac{\binom{45670}{699}\binom{30}{1}}{\binom{45700}{700}}$ which is approximately $0.2938 = 29.38\%$.

We can conclude : the answer to the second question is $1-p-p_1 = 7.69\%$

Comment: I agree with the chance to get at least one.  The chance to get at least two should be the chance to get at least one less the chance to get exactly one, so $37.07\%-29.38\%=7.69\%$

Comment: Wow, how did I messed my final calculation up ? Of course you're right, thank you ! It looks like you have to keep your attention until the last line ! x)

Comment: Thanks.  I got the first one at ~37%.  I was struggling with the second.  James